# Two different Authentication in asp.Net web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to implement token authentication and basic authentication in a single web API application. I have two different post methods. I need one method to use Token authentication (OWIN) and another one method to use without authentication ( or basic authentication). In the Startup.auth.cs we have configured the token authentication details. how to implement this or Is this possible and what will be the solution for this.

Comment: definitely possible, you can use `IAuthenticationFilter`

Comment: Thank you, I will check how to use this.